# h:selectOneRadio containing images

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I have a h:selectOneRadio tag for displaying a number of radiobuttons:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.radioButtonSelection}">
  <s:selectItems value="#{myBean.getPossibleRadioButtonSelections()}" var="rs" label="#{rs.toString}"/>                             
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Now, instead of radiobuttons with string values (labels), I would like to have radio buttons with (clickable) images next to it. Is this possible? If so, how?

Update:
Actually, there should be both text, and an image with a question mark which shows a modal panel when clicked on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<h:outputLabel for="form:radioGroupId:X">` and place a `<h:graphicImage>` inside. (X is the number of the option)

Of course you would have to have two collections - one with the items, and one with the pictures, and iterate them separately - one with `<s:selectItems>` and the other with `<ui:repeat>`. A little tedious.

Comment: How would you align this with `s:selectItems`?

Comment: I did something similar to your solution. The h:selectOneRadio creates a table, so I created a second table next to it (using <a:repeat>), containing the images... This works and looks fine, although the generated html code does not look very nice...

Answer (score 4):

Your best and most clean bet would be using CSS background images. Alternatively, you can also set `itemLabelEscaped="false"` and use plain vanilla HTML `<img>` in item label.

Comment: clickable CSS background images?
I actually need some <h:graphicImage>s, so I can show a modal panel when someone clicks on them. I don't think that would be possible with a background image.